# jQuery transform span into label and add attributes

Tags: jquery

```
<span>Autre contact :</span>

<label id="Autre contact :" for="">Autre contact :</label>
```

how can i transform a span into a label? and add an id and a for attribute?

Happy Friday :)

Comment: Not answering your question, but you have spaces in your `id` attribute, which makes it invalid. Is that your intent?

Comment: -1. Have you tried anything at all? This is as basica as javascript & jquery get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will do what you are looking for. There are of course variations, with the same outcome.

```
//use a jquery selector to grab the span
var span = $("span");

//generate a label object
var label = $("<label id='Something' for=''>Label Text</label>");

//replace the span
span.replaceWith(label);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('span').replaceWith(function () {
  var idAndText = $(this).text();
  return '<label id="' + idAndText + ' for="">' + idAndText + '</label>';
});
```

Note Ids should not contain spaces.  Therefore you may want to change your HTML or manipulate the id in the function above.

Comment: +1: This is good, but I'm wondering why noones is using the `attr()` function to assign the attributes? Any particular reason?

Comment: @JamesJohnson I really have don't have a reason.  The replaceWith function accepts HTML DOM Elements, jQuery Objects, or and HTML String.   I simply returned an HTML String for quick understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Others have given similar solutions, but here's a slightly different way:

```
$("#myspan").replaceWith(
    $("<label>").attr({ "id" : "myLabel", "value" : "foo", "for" : "otherElement" }));
```